# How do you find allowed HTTP methods in openshift deployment

Tags: docker, openshift

In classical application deployment, one could query the web server with HTTP method "OPTIONS" to discover allowed HTTP methods

On an openshift application deployement, how could we get that information ? I tried querying URLs using "curl -XOPTIONS" but I only get CORS allowed method at most. In some cases, I dont get any results.

Is there a way to verify that information in the openshift configuration ?